# Echo when counter is even but not zero

Tags: php, for-loop

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
if ($i % 2) { is odd } else { is even }
}
```

I have to start from 0 but I dont want it to appear as even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) 
{
    if($i == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if ($i % 2) 
    { 
         //is odd 
    } 
    else 
    { 
         //is even 
    }

}
```

It's that simple.  Continue will cause it to skip the rest of this particular iteration of the loop.  You could also do some code to handle 0 before the `continue`, as 0 is neither even nor odd.  Or you could make it the first part of the if/elseif/else structure.

Or instead of `if($i % 2)` you could do `if($i % 2 || $i == 0)` which would make it process through the odd code rather than even code.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
    if($i) {
        if ($i % 2) { is odd } else { is even }
    }
    // Other code
}
```

Or if you want to count 0 as odd:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
    if (!$i || $i % 2) { is odd } else { is even }
    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
if (i==0) {
  echo 'zero';
  } elseif ($i % 2 ==0) { 
  echo 'is even'; 
 } else { 
  echo 'is odd'; 
 }
}
```

OR

```
 for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
    if ($i !=0){
      if ($i % 2 ==0 { 
        echo 'is even'; 
      } else { 
        echo 'is odd'; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you really need starting your for loop from 0? you can easyly work this around by doing `for ($i=1; $i<=25; $i++)`

If you really need to start from 0 you can actually put a test for that special case:

```
if ($i === 0 || $i % 2) { is odd } else { is even }
```

Answer (score 0):

> for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
>   if ($i % 2 && $i != 0) { is odd } else { is even }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to iterate through the even values, this will sort it:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i+=2) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the most readable but it will be the most efficient:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
    if ($i)
        if ($i & 1) { is odd } else { is even }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need, unfortunately, an extra if...

```
    for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
echo (($i>0)?(($i % 2 )? "odd":"even"):"whatever");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add 1 more answer to this already well answered post:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++)
{
    if($i === 0) continue;
    if ($i % 2) { is odd } else { is even }
}
```

if you add `if($i === 0) continue;` it will skip the rest of the code and go to the next iteration.